# Debounce Function Empty TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I set up debounce inside my functional component like this:

```
const debouncedFunc= debounce(myFunction, 500);
```

I have the below TextField

```
    <TextField 
       id="myField" 
       maxLength={8}
       onChange={(e) => debouncedFunc(e.target?.value)} 
    />
```

I have the myFunction like this

```
  function myFunction(val) {
    if (val.length === 8) {
      console.log(val);
    }
  }
```

So this works well. It prints value when a user types eight characters into the field. The problem is that I need to empty the value in this field when a user types eight characters, and debounced function does kick in. Normally, TextField, I can empty the value in the field by `e.target.value=""`. Since I am in the debounce function, I do not have a reference to the `e`, so I cannot empty it.

Long question short, what is the best way to empty the textfield from a debounce function?

Comment: The "normal" react way would have been to put the value in a state and have the textbox whatch that state and the when you want to clear the textbox to set the state to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

My current and only solution is this, anyone that can think of a better solution please do share

```
export default function DebounceFeaturedTextfield() {
  const debouncedFunc= debounce(myFunction, 500);
  let TextFieldRef = "";
  function myFunction(val) {
    if (val.length === 8) {
      TextFieldRef.setInputValue("");
    }
  }
  return (
      <TextField 
      ref={(r) => {
        TextFieldRef = r;
      }}
       id="myField" 
       maxLength={8}
       onChange={(e) => debouncedFunc(e.target?.value)} 
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: The "normal" react way would have been to put the value in a state and have the textbox whatch that state and the when you want to clear the textbox to set the state to empty string. By using a ref to manipulate the value you are ignoring react which can only bring you pain  in the future